# Incompatible types when trying serialization with producer customizer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring for kafka, and I want to use the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer` to customize my producer factory because I need multiple value serializer, so I start with

```
  @Bean
  public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (producerFactory) -> {
      producerFactory.setKeySerializer(new StringSerializer());
    };
  }
```

But the compiler isn't happy

```
incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer cannot be 
converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<capture#1 of ?>
```

same issue with (I use the `ByteArraySerializer` to send message that failed to deserialize to dlq)

```
  producerFactory.setValueSerializer(
      new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(
          Map.of(
              byte[].class,
              new ByteArraySerializer(),
              Foo.class,
              new JsonSerializer<>())));
```

I got:

```
incompatible types: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DelegatingByTypeSerializer 
cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<capture#1 of ?>
```

but it work fine with just

```
producerFactory.setValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>());
```

the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer` class is defined like this

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer {

    /**
     * Customize the {@link DefaultKafkaProducerFactory}.
     * @param producerFactory the producer factory to customize
     */
    void customize(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory);

}
```

How to solve this issue ?

I know the other alternatives to configure `ValueSerialize` and `KeySerializer` but i want to know first why my code isn't working as excepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error on `setKeySerializer` goes away after casting the `producerFactory` variable from `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?>` to `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, ?>`. A similar cast works for `setValueSerializer` method as well. Bean definition below:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (producerFactory) -> {
        ((DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, ?>) producerFactory).setKeySerializer(new StringSerializer());
        ((DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, Object>) producerFactory)
                .setValueSerializer(new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(
                        Map.of(
                            byte[].class, 
                            new ByteArraySerializer(), 
                            Foo.class, 
                            new JsonSerializer<>())));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` is defined with wildcard types for its key and value serializers. Parameters sent to the `setKeySerializer` or `setValueSerializer` methods are not compatible with the specific serializer type. It's expecting `Serializer<?>` but you are providing `StringSerializer` or `DelegatingByTypeSerializer`.

Using the type cast (code below) should solve the problem;

```
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer() {
  return (producerFactory) -> {
    producerFactory.setKeySerializer((Serializer<String>) new StringSerializer());
  };
}



producerFactory.setValueSerializer((Serializer<Object>) new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(
      Map.of(
          byte[].class,
          new ByteArraySerializer(),
          Foo.class,
          new JsonSerializer<>())
));
```

Comment: it didn't work `incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<capture#1 of ?>`